# Combining 2 NSDateFormatters into one

Tags: ios, json, nsdateformatter

Currently I have two NSDateFormatters in my app and I want to somehow "combine" them so I only have, since they're parsing the same date.

I have a NSObject called UpcomingReleases, thats where all my JSON info gets stored.

UpcomingRelease.h

```
- (NSString *) formattedDate;
```

UpcomingRelease.m

```
- (NSString *) formattedDate {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
    NSDate *readableDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:self.release_date];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd"];
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:readableDate];
}
```

My UICollectionViewController (UpcomingReleasesViewController.m)

```
if([upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_date"] != NULL)
{
    NSString *readableDate = [upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_date"];
    UpcomingRelease *upcoming = [[UpcomingRelease alloc] init];
    upcoming.release_date = readableDate;

    cell.release_date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", upcoming.formattedDate];
}
```

My detailedViewController (ReleaseViewController.m)

(_singleRelease is a NSDictionary)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if([_singleRelease objectForKey:@"release_date"] != NULL)
    {
        NSString *readableDate = [_singleRelease objectForKey:@"release_date"];
        UpcomingRelease *singleRelease = [[UpcomingRelease alloc] init];
        singleRelease.release_date = readableDate;

        self.release_date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", singleRelease.formattedDate];
    }
}
```

This was working fine, until I added a share on twitter action and I had to add another NSDateFormatter so it could show the readable date inside the tweet (I would get an error saying "No visible interface for ReleaseViewController declares the selected 'formattedDate'" otherwise).

```
- (NSString *) formattedDate:(NSString *)jsonDateString {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
    NSDate *readableDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:jsonDateString];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd"];

    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:readableDate];
}

#pragma mark - Share on twitter
- (IBAction)shareOnTwitter:(id)sender {
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                               composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        NSString *formattedDate = [self formattedDate:[_singleRelease objectForKey:@"release_date"]];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", formattedDate]];

        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

How can I combine both these NSDateFormatters into one? They're both parsing the same string in the same way (also if there's a better way to show the formattedDate string than the one I'm currently doing would be great).

This is how my JSON shows the date string:

```
release_date: "2013-11-16T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your second version of formattedDate uses no values from the object instance.  It can be safely turned into a class (`+`) method so it can be invoked from anywhere.  And have the first version invoke the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hot Licks says:

Make the date formatter a class method:

```
+ (NSString *) formattedDate:(NSString *)jsonDateString {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
    NSDate *readableDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:jsonDateString];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd"];
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:readableDate];
}
```

Put it in a utility class and use it in both cases. In the first case just pass in `self.release_date`.

Comment: If you are parsing more than a few dates then the code above is inefficient, since it creates a new date formatter each time it is called, uses it once, then discards it. It would be better to write it to use a static variable to save a date formatter, and "lazy load" it the first time it's used. Then on each subsequent call you'd use the already-existing date formatter.

Comment: @Duncan While what you say is true I feel it is also a premature optimization. There are of course cases when what you suggest is necessary. C. A. R. Hoare:
"Premature optimization is the root of all evil in programming. "

Comment: So I should replace the code from my UpcomingRelease NSObject with your code? (I get a warning saying 'method definition for fomatteddate' not found). Also what I should I do so the date gets formatted in the tweet action? I'm still getting the error. (I'm parsing the date string 3 times, my viewcontroller, my detailedviewcontroller and in the tweet this page action. So let's say add a share to facebook or something would that make my app slower?)

Comment: @ChrisBedoya Yes. Meaningfully slower: No. Noticeably slower: No. Can you tell what a hundred nanoseconds feels like? There are cases where thousands of date formatter usages per second occur, that is starting to make a difference. The one time I saw this problem I identified it with the Instruments time profiler. But the answer was really a bad design and the answer was fixing the design.

Comment: @ChrisBedoya you need to put the class method definition in a header file and include that header file in the files where it is used. The file that has the code must be included in the project.

Comment: I created a utility class "NSString+DateFormatter" added the dateFormatter code, imported the class to my controller but I get an error here: NSString *formattedDate = [self formattedDate:[_singleRelease objectForKey:@"release_date"]]; saying that "no interface declares the selector formattedDate".

Comment: 1) do not name the class `NSString+DateFormatter`, that looks line a category, just name it something like `Utilities`. 2) Calling a class method is: [ClassName formattedDate:jsonDateString]; 3) Make sure the file is added to your project. 4) Get a good book in Objective-C iOS/OSX programming,possibly a "Big Nerd Ranch" book. This is rather simple stuff.

Comment: It is true that the code can be "optimized" by making the date formatter persistent.  This is far easier to do, of course, once the logic is in one place, vs being scattered around.  And doing so is a separate and distinct issue from addressing the OPs original issue.